# WPF Custom checkbox with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I want to have custom checkboxes in my application with images instead of the normal box. I also need to have different images depending on the checkbox so I thought I'd use a binding in my custom checkbox class to a class that has the images.

The C# code for my custom checkbox.

```
public class LogoCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    private Service _service;

    public Service Service
    {
        get { return (Service)GetValue(ServiceProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ServiceProperty, value);
            UncheckedImage = value.OtherLogo;
            CheckedImage = value.Logo;
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ServiceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Service", typeof(Service), typeof(LogoCheckBox));

    public ImageSource UncheckedImage { get; private set; }
    public ImageSource CheckedImage { get; private set; }
    public LogoCheckBox()
    {

    }
    void CheckedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Change displayed image
    }
}
```

I'm pretty stumped when it comes to styling the thing in XAML so I have the wanted behaviour.

My question is basically: Am I on the right track (this is a good way to achieve the functionality) and if it is how do I style it properly?

Comment: If you only want to change visual appearance, then the right way is to simply re-template default `CheckBox`. If, however, you will have complicated logic behind, then you may have to use custom control. From easiest to hardest: `UserControl`, new template, custom control (often with custom draw). So the real question is why do you go the hardest way? Do you use MVVM? Image for combobox can be provided by VM (via simple binding), while logic of which image to use either a part of VM itself, converter or (in complicated cases) behavior. For reusing - `UserControl` with own VM will do perfectly.

Comment: you can use ToggleButton instead , and can set image as content

Comment: Using togglebutton and changing the binding seems to get the functionality I want. Thanks.